# How can I resize a image file in Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin

My app takes photos and saves them inside the cellphone, however when my list loads many photos it becomes very slow, that is why I need to lower the resolution to the photos. How can I do that?

This is how I create the picture

```
fun createImage():File{
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageName = "JPEG_"+timeStamp+"_"
        var storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        var image = File.createTempFile(imageName,".jpg",storageDir)

        currentPath=image.absolutePath
        return image
    }
```

This is how I load the picture

```
  var beerPhoto: ImageView?=null
  ....
  viewHolder.beerPhoto?.setImageURI(Uri.parse(userDto.beerPhoto))
```

Comment: the solution was to use Glide, thx guys

Answer (score 2):

You can use glide to resize your image and scaling purposes it's pretty much easier

```
GlideApp  
    .with(context)
    .load(userDto.beerPhoto)
    .override(600, 200)  // it don't maintain aspect ratio 
    .into(beerPhoto);
```

To maintain aspect ratio you can use explicitly scale images

```
GlideApp  
    .with(context)
    .load(userDto.beerPhoto)
    .override(600, 200)
    .centerCrop() // or use fitcenter
    .into(beerPhoto);
```

Comment: Thx, this works fine! 
just 1 question, i have a kt Class and a layout without activity, what should i put in context?

Comment: craete a class which extent your application class inside which you have static method getApplicationContext which you can call to get context
`companion object {
        lateinit var yourApplication: App
  
        fun getApplicationContext(): Context {
            return yourApplication.applicationContext
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Please use Glide for load images from server and resize it . It's very easy and useful for you I think .

Please check below link for more detail for resize image

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

> repositories
>    {
>
> mavenCentral()
>
> google()
>
> }
>
> dependencies
>
> {
>    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
>
> annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
>   }